# Plot a 2D array with axes labelled with the array values of a 1D array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, plotly

I have a 1D array `arr1d = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']`  and I have a 2D array

`arr2d =[[1, 2, 5, 3], [2, 1, 2, 5], [5, 3, 4, 4], [5, 5, 3, 4]]`  (say)
I wish to plot the array using matplotlib (or any other library) in such a way that the output is in the following manner.
I want the x and y axis to get labelled as per the 1D array as shown in the picture.
How to achieve that?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import colors
import numpy as np

arr1d = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
data = np.array([[1, 2, 5, 3], [2, 1, 2, 5], [5, 3, 4, 4], [5, 5, 3, 4]])
cmap = colors.ListedColormap(['blue','red', 'green', 'yellow', 'cyan'])
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(data, cmap=cmap)

for (i, j), z in np.ndenumerate(data):
    ax.text(j, i, '{}'.format(z), ha='center', va='center', size=12)
    
plt.xticks(np.arange(len(arr1d)), arr1d)
plt.yticks(np.arange(len(arr1d)), arr1d)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Using `ListedColormap`, you can decide which number is mapped to which color.

Or with grid lines:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import colors
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.ticker import (AutoMinorLocator, MultipleLocator)

arr1d = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
data = np.array([[1, 2, 5, 3], [2, 1, 2, 5], [5, 3, 4, 4], [5, 5, 3, 4]])
cmap = colors.ListedColormap(['blue','red', 'green', 'yellow', 'cyan'])

_, ax = plt.subplots()
for (i, j), z in np.ndenumerate(data):
  ax.annotate('{}'.format(z), xy = (j + 0.4, i + 0.6), fontsize=15)

ax.imshow(data, cmap=cmap, extent=(0, data.shape[0], data.shape[1], 0))
ax.grid(color='black', linewidth=3)

plt.xticks(np.arange(len(arr1d)), arr1d)
plt.yticks(np.arange(len(arr1d)), arr1d)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve a result close to what you need with [matshow](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.matshow.html#matplotlib-axes-axes-matshow) in matplotlib.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
arr1d = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
arr2d =[[1, 2, 5, 3], [2, 1, 2, 5], [5, 3, 4, 4], [5, 5, 3, 4]]
plt.matshow(arr2d)
plt.xticks([0,1,2,3], arr1d)
plt.yticks([0,1,2,3], arr1d)
plt.show()
```

[image: result]